# Can I connect to any terminal for batteries in parallel?

Tags: batteries, dc, parallel

If I have a bank of batteries wired in parallel, can I use any of the negative terminals as my negative output? Can I use different terminals for different leads? For example, battery 1 and battery 2 both have negative terminals. Can I use one terminal for one output and another terminal for another?

Comment: Title says parallel, question says series.

Comment: Fixed. Should be parallel.

Comment: If I have understood the question correctly, then yes, you can connect two different circuits to either of the battery's terminals because they should be at the same voltage or potential.

Comment: @EdinFifić You said it yourself; "should", which isn't always true. We don't know what batteries these are, and for longer life, say in a boat, the batteries are wired in parallel but you would connect external connections to opposite batteries to balance out the wire resistance between batteries. For shorter life you can connect the external wires to same battery, but why would you want to deliberately ruin the batteries.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the explanation. These are two 12V 100Ah AGM batteries for an RV.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of high-current systems, it's advisable to wire the batteries, as shown below, in order to equalise the cable length / voltage drop for each battery.

[image]

Comment: I have two 12V 100 Ah batteries. That is probably considered low-current, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on the load.

Comment: Simple, yet effective trick.